# how to implement unicode to ascii coding in java?

Tags: java, unicode, arduino

I have this coding which is a serial port communication coding.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
        /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
            "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                        "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
            "COM22", // Windows
    };
    /**
    * A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
    * converting the bytes into characters 
    * making the displayed results codepage independent
    */
    private BufferedReader input;
    /** The output stream to the port */
    private OutputStream output;
    /** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    /** Default bits per second for COM port. */
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
                // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
                // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
                //System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This should be called when you stop using the port.
     * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
     */
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
     */
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                
        
            
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
    }
```

}
`

The output is like this:

> Started
>
> Start
>
> ŠÉ“RãL^Ï?™M²0Œå

So, how I want to put another coding which is Unicode to ASCII coding inside that coding? What is the easiest way for me to decrypt the encrypted data? For your information, this serial port communication is to read data from arduino. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `String.getBytes()` to go from Unicode -> UTF-8 and `new String(byte[])` to go the other way?  And no,you cannot go from Unicode --> ASCII unless the "Unicode" consists of only ASCII code points.

Comment: This look like the other end uses 7-bit with parity. It is much easier if both ends are configured identically. Can you make an existing serial communications program work?

Comment: where should i implement this code? in which part of coding?

Comment: yes the existing serial communications program work without any problems. right now the problem is to decrypt the output.

Comment: 'String inputLine=input.readLine();
byte[] byteText = inputLine.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
String originalString= new String(byteText , "UTF-8");
System.out.println(originalString);'    The output still : ŠÉ“RãL^Ï?™M²0Œå  .How i can change it to readable word?

Comment: please post an [MCVE]. I think the help requested can be demonstrated in a much shorter code.

Comment: You don't mention how Arduino has configured its Serial and what and it sends. Where does the word "start" come from? A char in Arduino c++ is 8 bits. So beyond ASCII it might be UTF-8, but that's not for sure.

Comment: the word "start" just only from system.out.println to notify that the serial communication can be used. P

Comment: I just see ** System.out.println("Started"); ** But the Arduino side is still more interesting...